# Assign variables into row numbers in excel

Tags: excel

A simple Question, my first row is like: `1,3,5,2,6,4,...`

Then I would like my second row is: `=R1C1`, `=R3C1`, `=R5C1`, =`R2C1`, =`R6C1`, `=R4C1`....

In a word, I would "read" the first line as my row number in one certain column.
Is there a function like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX.  Assuming B1 is the `1`, Put this in B2 and copy over:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,B1)
```

[image]

---

If one has the Dynamic Array formula then just putting:

```
=INDEX(A:A,B1:G1)
```

in B2 would suffice, Excel will spill the results across.

[image]